# How to change a power of limit to use Taylor series?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions, taylor-expansion

How to solve $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{a^\frac{1}{n} + b^\frac{1}{n}}{2}\right)^n$?

I tried to decompose it by Taylor series but it is impossible because $n\to\infty$. I don't know how to make $\frac{1}{n}$ power to from $n$ to use Taylor series.

Comment: Hint: $$
a^{1/n}  = \exp \left( {\frac{{\log a}}{n}} \right) = 1 + \frac{{\log a}}{n} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{n^2 }}} \right)
$$ for any fixed $a>0$ as $n\to +\infty$.

Comment: @Gary I did it with a and b, but then I met a power $n$ behind parentheses and that's the problem)

Comment: Do you know the limit of $\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n$ as $n\to +\infty$? It is $e^x$.

Comment: Yes. But how to get n in denominator then?

Comment: Please edit your question by adding your progress so far.

Comment: I understood what you meant. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $a,b>0$.

We have
$$
 \left(\frac{a^\frac{1}{n} + b^\frac{1}{n}}{2}\right)^n
=a\, \left(\frac{1+ r^\frac{1}{n}}{2}\right)^n,
$$
where $r=b/a$. We can write
\begin{align}
a\, \left(\frac{1+ r^\frac{1}{n}}{2}\right)^n
&=a\, \left(1-\frac{1- r^\frac{1}{n}}{2}\right)^n
=a\,\exp\Big[n\,\log\Big(1-\frac{1- r^\frac{1}{n}}{2}\Big)\Big]\\[0.3cm]
&=a\,\exp\Big[n\,\log\Big(1-\frac{1- e^{\frac1n\log r}}{2}\Big)\Big]\\[0.3cm]
&=a\,\exp\Big[n\,\log\Big(1-\frac{- \frac1n\log r+o\big(\frac1{n^2}\big)}{2}\Big)\Big]\\[0.3cm]
&=a\,\exp\Big[n\,\log\Big(1+\frac1{2n}\log r+o\big(\frac1{n^2}\big)\Big)\Big]\\[0.3cm]
&=a\,\exp\Big[\,\frac1{2}\log r+o\big(\frac1{n}\big)\Big)\Big]\\[0.3cm]
&\to a\,e^{\frac12\,\log r}=a\,r^{1/2}=\sqrt{ab}.
\end{align}

Comment: Solution is great but it is a little bit sad to understand that I had no chance to guess this solution)

Comment: I just used the Taylor series for the exponential and for $\log(1+x)$, both up to first order. The change of the fraction from $\frac{1+s}2$ to $1-\frac{1-s}2$ is precisely to be able to use $\log(1+x)$. In summary, I just used $e^x=1+x+o(x^2)$ and $\log(1+x)=x+o(x^2)$.